# Which arithmetic operator can produce not NaN result when one of operands will be NaN?

Tags: javascript, math

Just for interest. We have that NaN is spreading along side calculation.

```
1 + NaN => NaN
```

Is there any operator which will stop this spreading. I mean something like:

```
<operator> NaN => number
```

or

```
NaN <operator> <operand> => number
```

or

```
<operand> <operator> NaN => number
```

NaN => number

Comment: Question I have is why would you not handle the situation before it gets that far. Detect if it is a number, if not do something else. What are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: Totaly agree with you.

My question was pure theoretical question. Previously I thought that all numeric operators return NaN when NaN is passed as one of the parameters. But I found that it was not true.

I wanted to share this information with all.

Initially I read wiki article about 0**0. And found that as a convention in many languages 0**0 is equal to 1. And found that in Javascript it's also the case. But after reading more I found that this operator returns 1 regardless of any number, including NaN. So I've decided to share it with all of stack overflow readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually in Ecmascript definition of (**) operator for numbers. Has a special case when second operand is +0 or -0.

https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-data-types-and-values.html#sec-numeric-types-number-exponentiate

So actually:

```
console.log(NaN ** 0) // will log 1
```

Comment: Hmm, even `'abc' ** 0` equals to `1`. This somewhat contradicts the words "exponentiate takes arguments base (a Number)".

Comment: @YuriGinsburg Actually not. This operation `exponentiate` is not the same as `**` operator.

This function is called after transforming of both operands to numbers. Actual ** definition is defined here:

https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-applystringornumericbinaryoperator

You can see that operator firstly converts values to numeric values and only after checking that both was successfuly converted - calls `exponentiate`. Since both NaN and 0 has type number definition is not wrong. But ** is defined not only for numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript has a built-in method that detect a NaN, but you will need check this "Possible number" for each operand.

```
let possibleNumber = "4f";

console.log(isNaN(Number(possibleNumber)));

possibleNumber = "44";

console.log(isNaN(Number(possibleNumber)));
```

Output:

```
true
false
```

You can do some function to check and return some number that you want

```
function checkIfIsNaN(number,numIfTrue,numIfFalse){
    if(isNaN(Number(number))){ return numIfTrue} else{return numIfFalse};
}

console.log(checkIfIsNaN("44",4,10));
```

Comment: Thank you for you're answer. It's not actually answer on my question.  


My question was not about "How to handle possible NaN values in the program. I know that if it's possible we should avoid even creation of such values.  

For those who find this answer useful for their situation I want to add that there is also interesting functions:  

Number.isFinite - will check if value is not NaN and +Infinity, -Infinity.  
Number.isSafeInteger - will check if value is integer and small enough for accurate integer operators.